# passing an image/picture as an argument to a function in android studio?

Tags: java, android, function, android-drawable, imagebutton

How can I pass an image/picture as an argument to a function in android studio?

I have pic1.jpg, pic2.jpg, pic3.jpg, and pic4.jpg in drawable folder, and I have something like this:

```
private void exampleFunction() {
   ImageButton key1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.game.R.id.key1);
   ImageButton key2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.game.R.id.key2);
   ImageButton key3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.game.R.id.key3);
   ImageButton key4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.game.R.id.key4);

   if ( condition1) {
    key1.setImageResource(com.example.game.R.drawable.pic1);
    key2.setImageResource(com.example.game.R.drawable.pic2);
   } 
   else if ( condition2 ) {
        key3.setImageResource(com.example.game.R.drawable.pic3);
        key4.setImageResource(com.example.game.R.drawable.pic4);
   }
}
```

How can I do it like this:

```
private void exampleFunction() {
   ImageButton key1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.game.R.id.key1);
   ImageButton key2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.game.R.id.key2);
   ImageButton key3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.game.R.id.key3);
   ImageButton key4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(com.example.game.R.id.key4);
   if ( condition1) {
       assignPics (key1, key2, pic1, pic2);
   } 
   else if ( condition2 ) {
       assignPics (key3, key4, pic3, pic4);
   }    
}


private void assignPics( ImageButton p1, ImageButton p2, ...how should I receive picture1-2 here ) {
     p1.setImageResource( ?? picture1 ?? );
     p2.setImageResource( ?? picture2 ?? );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ids are `int` values in Android, so `assignPics` function should look as follows:

```
private void assignPics(ImageButton p1, ImageButton p2, int id1, int id2) {
    p1.setImageResource(id1);
    p2.setImageResource(id2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If imgkey denotes the key of your img like pic1, pic2, etc., And you know the keys,, then try this. K=((ImageButton)view).setImageResource(R.drawable.imgkey); Use this to assign your pictures to the image buttons. Hope this helps. :)